# Core Data using auto generated Primary Key PK

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a simple Person entity in Core Data, I noticed that when adding data, each row is auto generated a unique **PK** called **objectID**

I wish to retrieve the records using the objectID but I am getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath objectID not found in
>   entity < NSSQLEntity Person id=2 >'

```
func fetchPerson(withID personID: Int,
                 context: NSManagedObjectContext,
                 completion: @escaping ([Person]?) -> Void) {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(#keyPath(Person.objectID)) == \(personID)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    //perform aynchronous operation:
    context.perform {
        do {
            let persons = try fetchRequest.execute()
            //success - return array of persons
            completion(persons)
        } catch {
            //error - return nil
            completion(nil)
        }

    }

}
```

Calling the above :

```
//fetch person with specific id:
let personID: Int = 2
fetchPerson(withID: personID, context: persistentContainer.viewContext) { (persons: [Person]?) in
    if persons != nil {

        print("Fetching person with personID: \(personID)")
        for person in persons! {
            print("Person: \(person.objectID) - \(person.firstName!) \(person.lastName!)")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `objectID` is a property of `NSManagedObject` but is not the name of a field in the persistent store or part of the entity description. You can't use it in predicates because it's not there to use as a filter. There *is* a field in the primary store that corresponds to the object ID, but it's also not available to fetch requests because that's not how Core Data is intended to be used.

If you want a primary key with Core Data, you need to create it yourself. Or if you really want SQL-style coding, use SQLite directly and don't get Core Data involved.

Comment: Interesting, so best to ignore the primary key and use own value instead.

Comment: Yes. Core Data normally maintains referential integrity via relationships. Those will be backed up by the internal private keys, but that's an implementation detail. Be careful not to think too much about SQL when using Core Data, because it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch with objectID by using the predicate `"self == %@", objectID`. An objectID is property of a managedObject and its type is `NSManaged​Object​ID` not an `Int`.  In general it is better to create and manage your own objectId. I generally use UUID strings.

Comment: However, that requires a NSManaged​Object​ID, and will not work with `let personID: Int = 2` as in the question.

Comment: Which makes you wonder why they create a primary key for you but don't let you access it. Seem to be encouraging us to break the rules of referential integrity.